# Marmalade UIBuilder missing?

Tags: android, ios, marmalade, uibuilder

I was reading the [Marmalade UIBuilder Tutorial](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/documentation#/tools/uibuilder/uibuildertutorialapp.html) and it says to open the UIBuilder. I have seen no such program with my download. Where can I get the UIBuilder? Why was it not included in my download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Marmalade 6.0, then please see the [Documentation on the UIBuilder](https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/documentation#/tools/uibuilder.html). It states that:

> We have removed the UI Builder because we believe that, going forwards, it is better for the Marmalade UI runtimes to support a standard UI markup rather than our proprietary markup. In the 6.1 release, we plan to support a standard UI markup, meaning that developers can leverage multiple 3rd party tools (including free tools) that support that markup.
>
> Our plan for the 6.0.1 release is to make the UI Builder source code publicly available, together with full instructions on how to build it. In the meantime, developers can still use the UI Builder tool by installing the most recent 5.2.x SDK version.

aka they have not included the UIBuilder so that more standard UIBuilders can be used. But they also say that you can download the old [5.2.x SDK version](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/SDK-DDK/Airplay-SDK.shtml). Hope this helps!

Comment: Bump to this question, what do we use with 6.1 then? I've googled marmalade ui builder and nothing comes up. Has nobody made a UI builder yet?